# Core Data Compound Index on parent property

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have an abstract Entity Event and a sub entity of that SpecificEvent.
Event has property created_at. SpecificEvent has additional properties

I'm trying to create a compound index on SpecificEvent including created_at (the parent super property), but I get an error compiling the data model:

> UserDataModel.xcdatamodeld/UserDataModel.xcdatamodel: In the Compound Indexes attribute for entity SpecificEvent, created_at is not a valid property

It looks like xcode can't find the parent property because all other properties work. Is there a way to fix this or is it just a limitation? I searched through the docs but couldn't find anything on indexing parent properties, and very little on compound indexing in general.

Comment: Nope. As a temporary workaround I removed the abstract model and just repeated the fields in the child model. I keep the abstract class in the code though, just not in the xcdatamodel